# Use Django ModelChoice field to create pulldown to lookup table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to implement a pulldown field that contains a list of country names in a Customer Billing Information form using the ModelChoiceField field.  However, when I try to render the form, I'm getting "AttributeError, 'str' object has no attribute 'all'" and I don't know what's causing it.

I have a lookup table that contains country codes and names:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
class Country(models.Model):
    # Ex: code = 'us', name = 'United States'
    country_cd = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I then have a Customer model and associated Customer Billing Information modelform that contains a foreign key field to point to the above lookup table:

```
# models.py
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    # Other fields...

# forms.py
from django import forms
from app.models import Customer, Country
class CustomerBillingInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('country',)

    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='Country.objects.all()', empty_label=None)
```

I've run this in the debugger and doing "type(country)" does show that it's a QuerySet and that "Country.objects.all()" is returning all of the countries in my "country" database.  The stacktrace says the error is being raised at line 896 of the /django/forms/models.py module (Django v. 1.4) in the 'ModelChoiceIterator' class.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='Country.objects.all()',
    empty_label=None)
```

to:

```
country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(),
    empty_label=None)
```

Comment: Thank you, Brandon.  That mistake was a real "forehead slapper" and just goes to show that it doesn't pay to sit up all night coding.  I'll credit you with the answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: No worries :) I love when I'm editing the wrong file and wondering why my changes aren't showing up.